# Can't start Mongo shell on Windows: "connection attempt failed"

Tags: mongodb

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongo

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-08-11T15:37:19.430+0800 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-08-11T15:37:19.433+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

My PC's local IP address is not 127.0.0.1

Originally I had localhost mapped to the PC's local IP address in the Windows hosts file.

I changed this to: `127.0.0.1 localhost` in hosts, but the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Comment: What's your PC localhost IP if it's not 127.0.0.1? Also, do you have `mongod` running in your PC?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha localhost IP can be 127.0.0.1 and is set as such in hosts.. WIFI IP is 10.0.0.21. Yes, I have `mongod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create data/db directory and give the below command.
mongod --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data

It will start running at 27017 port. If pou want to change the port then add --port portnumber

Assuming you have already set the environment variable

Comment: How do I set the environment variable Gaurav?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try connecting using `mongo --host <host>`?

Comment: If I use `mongo --host P300` where P300 is my hostname, I receive the same original error. If I use `mongo --host localhost` the error is the same again.